# Group child category IDs based on their parent category

Tags: terms, categories

I have IDs for my child categories, `11,14,21,35,38,39`, where these all are various child categories from their main category:

- Parent category `1` has: `11,14`
- Parent category `2` has: `21`
- Parent category `3` has: `35,38,39`

How can I group my child IDs as per their parent category, like below?

```
array(
    1 => array ( 11,14 ),
    2 => array ( 21 ),
    3 => array ( 35,38,39 )
)
```

Comment: Do you mean that you literally want array of IDs structured like that or something else? What are you trying to accomplish with it?

Comment: Yes, I want array of IDs structured like that and I can use those array to display some posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick take would be something like this:

```
$categories        = [ ];
$parent_categories = get_categories( [ 'parent' => 0 ] );

foreach ( $parent_categories as $parent_category ) {
    $id                = $parent_category->term_id;
    $categories[ $id ] = wp_list_pluck( get_categories( [ 'parent' => $id ] ), 'term_id' );
}
```

The important bit is a `parent` argument, which limits retrieved to immediate children (parent of 0 is a top level).

Depending on how *many* of these you have it might be preferable to instead retrieve all of them first and then re-arrange out of singe result set.

Comment: I was looking to doing something like this. I was just short of `wp_list_pluck` function, I was not aware of it and was looking for it. We can use `child_of` instead of `parent`, in the `wp_list_pluck` to include its all descedant.

Comment: One more thing, its making array of all the `parent = > child` array, I only need the array, for my given child cats IDs. How about that ?

Comment: Pass them in `include` argument probably.

Comment: I have used `array_intersect()` to take out the matching value from this array. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same requirement as you. The below piece of code is my solution:

```
$termArr = array();
$termIds = array_filter(explode(',','11,14,21,35,38,39'),'is_numeric');
if( !empty($termIds) ){
    $terms = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'my_taxonomy',
        'include' => $termIds
    ));

    foreach($terms as $t){
        if( !isset($termArr[$t->parent]) )
            $termArr[$t->parent] = array();
        $termArr[$t->parent][] = $t->term_id;
    }

    print_r($termArr); //===> This is the array which you need :)
}
```